# Spring boot Swagger UI exception at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to get Swagger UI to work in my project and I'm following [these docs](https://springdoc.org/#Introduction), but whatever I try my application instantly crashes with the following exception:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'swaggerWebMvcConfigurer' defined in
> class path resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'swaggerWebMvcConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'indexPageTransformer' defined in class
> path resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'indexPageTransformer'
> parameter 3; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'swaggerWelcome' defined in class path
> resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]:
> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc] from ClassLoader
> [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]

I'm using Kotlin with Spring Boot and these are my Gradle dependencies:

```kotlin
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
implementation("com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:3.14.0")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.1")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.13.2")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.6.6")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6")
implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta")
implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin")
implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen")
implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven")
implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10")
implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1")
implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.0.5")
implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.4")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3")
```

I've tried a lot of different packages in a lot of different combinations, but it will always throw an exception at startup.

Plugins section of Gradle file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "8.5.4"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "7.1.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20-RC"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.20-RC"
}
```

Comment: `Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]` probably means that the `SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc` class is not available on the ClassPath. Can you add more details from your gradle file, including the plugins section?

Comment: @MarkAbersold I've added the plugin section of my Gradle build file.

Comment: I think you are missing: springdoc-openapi-security, springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core dependecies (and probably springdoc-openapi-data-rest also)

Comment: @pringi unfortunately it still won't work.

Comment: You are using springBoot v3. Springdoc only supports v1 and v2.

Comment: springdoc-openapi-ui is important dependency here.
can you check if it got excluded.
you can check with `gradle build dependencies` command

Comment: @pringi so how do I integrate the Open API standard (with/without UI) in my app?

Comment: If pringi is right you have to use the latest stable SpringBoot Version which is 2.6.6: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 will use Jakarta EE while Spring Boot 2 still uses Java EE. This move includes a namespace change for the Servlet API from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`. Your application fails because Springdoc 1.x tries to load classes from the old namespace but Spring Boot 3 only pulls in the new namespace.

Springdoc has released a milestone release that works with Jakarta EE and the milestone releases of Spring Boot 3: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1284

In a Java application, you can replace

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6'
```

with

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.0-M1'
```

There is also an official Maven example here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/2.x/demo-spring-boot-3-webmvc

If you only include the starter into a Kotlin project with

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.0-M1")
```

this seems to work fine and generates the Swagger UI. But it seems there is currently no corresponding milestone release for `springdoc-openapi-kotlin`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Do you by any chance know how to use the Gradle plugin (org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin) as well? The current version (1.3.4) also crashes.